# How do I output execvp on a single line?

Tags: shell, unix, ls, execvp, minix

I need help, i am trying to create a shell in minix3, and i want to create my own "ls" command, so at the moment i am using the `execvp` command. The only problem is that i would like it to all output on a single line, instead of each directory on their own line.  I have been attempting to get this correct for quite some time and i just cant seem to get it right.  I am not sure if this is possible or not but any advice on how to achieve the final product without having to use `system()` would be greatly appreciated!

Example of my Code:

```
char* arg[] = {"ls", "-1", NULL};
execvp(arg[0], arg);
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to pipe the output of `ls` to [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr). You could use complicated code to set up pipelines, or you could invoke `sh` with a script instead:

```
char const* args[] = {"sh", "-c", "ls | tr '\n' ' '", NULL};
execvp(args[0], args);
```

Or if you're fine with commas between the entries, pass the `-m` flag to `ls`:

```
char const* args[] = {"ls", "-m", NULL};
execvp(args[0], args);
```